# Change TextBlock Foreground when Pressed

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, textblock

I was referencing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645061(v=vs.95).aspx in order to change the foreground of the textblock text when it is pressed, but I am getting an error on line `<Setter Property="Template">` stating that `The member 'Template' is not recognized or is not accessible`. I would like to, by default, set the foreground to the device's `PhoneAccentBrush` and then when pressed set the foreground to `PhoneDisabledBrush` (the grayish color). How might I accomplish this in WP8?

```
<Style x:Key="TextBlockStyle1" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{StaticResource PhoneHorizontalMargin}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template"> <!-- Error: The member 'Template' is not recognized or is not accessible. -->
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                        <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#FF99C1E2" Duration="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextBlock has no Template property. As work around you can make a Button and customize it as TextBlock.

Here is an example:

```
        <Button Content="Test"
                Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Txt">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                                Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                                    <TextBlock x:Name="Txt"
                                               Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                               Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />

                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
```